# How can I reuse dynamic email to another request in jmeter

Tags: validation, email, jmeter, return-value

There is a form with email validation, once you enter email, it will check if the same email existing or not followed by submiting the form.

I want to know how can I use the same email to next request.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor), choose Field to check as `Request Headers`

and use Regular expression to match headers in request as `email: mymail@mydomain.com`

```
email: ([^\t\n]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) name of your choice as the 3rd parameter for the [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) like:

```
${__Random(10000000,99999999,randomNumber)}
```

this way JMeter will generate a random number and store it into `${randomNumber}` JMeter Variable which you will be able to reuse later on where required:

[image]

More information: [Using JMeter Functions - Part II](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733739-Using-JMeter-Functions-Part-II)